# How to open a Popup in Leaflet as Hover and not on Click

Tags: angularjs, hover, leaflet

I want to open the popup in Angular Leaflet as a hover and not on click.

I have a markers array initialized and an overlay of a layer on top of the base layer.

I am trying to create a layer where buses and bus stops belong to each other. So each layer belongs to the same type in the overlays.

I am using the code

```
markers = [];
markers.push(
{ layer : layername,
          lat : latitude,
          lng : longitude,
          message: busNames(data),
   icon :{....}
 }
 });
```

I have another push marker set on the same layer which builds busStop data.

Now how do I display the popups when mouse is moved over them as hover instead of showing them on click

P.S - I am new to coding and hence please help me with proceeding further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each marker you are creating you have to listen to 'mouseover' and 'mouseout' events.

You open the popup when 'mouseover' is sent, close it when 'mouseout' is sent.

```
    var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map);
    var tooltipPopup;

    marker.on('mouseover', function(e) { 
    tooltipPopup = L.popup({ offset: L.point(0, -50)});
            tooltipPopup.setContent("Hello");
            tooltipPopup.setLatLng(e.target.getLatLng());
            tooltipPopup.openOn(map);

    });

    marker.on('mouseout', function(e) { 
        map.closePopup(tooltipPopup);
    });
```

Here is an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/TdfUjkDz1zl6ukvqV8WC?p=preview)

Comment: I am using Angular Leaflet and not just Leaflet so, the "message" that is being used in the example shown above creates my popup. So in that case how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to include  'leafletData' to your controller, after that add 'mouseover' and 'mouseout' events to your Marker.

```
angular
.module('myapp')
.controller("EventsController", [ '$scope', 'leafletData', function($scope, leafletData) {

  $scope.$on('leafletDirectiveMarker.mouseover', function(event, args){
    console.log('I am over!');
    var popup = L.popup({ offset: L.point(0, -28)})
                .setLatLng([args.model.lat, args.model.lng])
                .setContent(args.model.message)
    leafletData.getMap().then(function(map) {
      popup.openOn(map);
    });
  });

  $scope.$on('leafletDirectiveMarker.mouseout', function(event){
    leafletData.getMap().then(function(map) {
      map.closePopup();
    });
  });
}]);
```